# C programming - pthread_create() loop index as argument

Tags: c, multithreading

I have following c code that has some problems.

I want to realize a matrix multiplication (1dim arrays) with threads

```
pthread_t thread[ARRAY_SIZE];


void* mmult(void* r){
   int row = (intptr_t) r;         
   int index;                                
   int column, tmp, size = ARRAY_SIZE;
   for(column = 0; column < size; column++){ 
      tmp = 0;
      for(index = 0; index < size; index++){
         tmp += MA[row * size + index]  *  MBT[column * size + index];
      }
      MC[row * size + column] = tmp;
   }

   pthread_exit(NULL);      


}
int main(void) {
   int size = ARRAY_SIZE, row, column;
   struct timeval start, end;
   double exectime;

   init_matrix(MA); //function to create Matrix
   init_matrix(MB);



   for(row = 0; row < size; row++){ /* create Array-Threads */

      if(pthread_create(&thread[row], NULL, &mmult,&row) != 0){ //also doesnt work with (void*) &row
         perror("Fehler beim Erstellen eines Feld-Threads");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

   int i;
   for(i =0; row < size; i++){
      status = pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
   }


   return 0;
}
```

I have `Matrix MA` and `Matrix MB` and `Matrix MBT` where the values are switched to multiply it with `MA`.

The size of my `Matrix` is defined by `ARRAY_SIZE * ARRAY_SIZE`

I am trying to create a thread for every row of the matrix and multiply row with column in my function `mmult`.

The error message I get is : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: "If you do not know why your code did not work, that suggests you have not debugged it. Debugging is one of the first steps developers take when their code fails, and is an important skill to learn.Without debugging, you risk wasting the time of those who are trying to help you."

Answer (score 2):

Even though you haven't created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us (which you really should have) it's easy to guess what the problem is.

Take a closer look at how you create your thread:

```
pthread_create(&thread[row], NULL, &mmult,&row)
```

Here you pass a pointer to the variable `row`. Now for how you use the argument in the thread function:

```
int row = (intptr_t) r;
```

But `r` is a *pointer* to an `int`, it's not the value of the current "row" when creating the thread.

It would be more correct to do

```
int row = *(int *) r;
```

***But*** this will lead to another problem: All thread function will be called with the very same pointer, all pointing to the very same place. And since you have no control over when threads start to run, you don't know if all threads will get different values for `row` or if there might be duplicates.

To solve this you need to pass the *value* of the `row` variable when creating the thread. This is one of the few places where it's considered okay to cast a value to a pointer. It actually needs two casts:

```
pthread_create(&thread[row], NULL, &mmult,(void *) (intptr_t) row)
```

Now you need to do the opposite when getting the value inside the thread:

```
int row = (int) (intptr_t) r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is already a `void *`, there's no need to pass it by reference. You're passing a reference to the `void *` instead of passing `void *` itself. Instead try `pthread_create(&thread[row], NULL, mmult, &row)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax of the function `pthread_create`.

`int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);`

The first argument is of type `pthread_t` and represents the thread id although there might be some other errors.